# WebFlux returning http.okay vice http.notFound

Tags: functional-programming, httpresponse, spring-webflux

New to WebFlux, reactive, and handlers. I've got things "working", but am not understanding why following code is returning "okay" with empty body, vice "not found".

Clarification: The issue-of-concern is in the final return statement of *DemoPOJOHandler.getById()*. The "short-circuit" code works as expected (i.e., returns "Bad Request" status), but the "switchIfEmpty" path of the final return statement does not appear to get exercised if a *DemoPOJORepo.getById(int)* returns *Mono.empty()*.

(Note: I've hacked up a list-based "repo" to avoid dealing with database while figuring out handlers and http return types.)

Router implementation ("/v1" is a set of annotation based RESTful endpoints)...

```
@Configuration
public class DemoPOJORouter {

    @Bean
    public RouterFunction<ServerResponse> route(DemoPOJOHandler requestHandler) {
        return nest(path("/v2"),
               nest(accept(APPLICATION_JSON),
               RouterFunctions.route(RequestPredicates.GET("/DemoPOJO"), requestHandler::getAll)
                           .andRoute(RequestPredicates.GET("/DemoPOJO/{id}"), requestHandler::getById)
                           .andRoute(RequestPredicates.POST("/DemoPOJO"), requestHandler::add)));
    }
}
```

Handler implementation has been "stripped down" to only the code in question. I have a feeling that much of the style is "still imperative", but I've attempted to put the reactive stuff where it "makes the most sense".

If I supply a bad value on the URI (i.e., "foo"), then I get the http "bad request" returned. But, never seem to get the "not found" that should be generated by "*switchIfEmpty*" if a validly formatted int value is supplied, but it does not map to an entry in the repo.

```
@Component
public class DemoPOJOHandler {

    public static final String PATH_VAR_ID = "id";

    private DemoPOJORepo repo = null;

    public Mono<ServerResponse> getById(ServerRequest request) {
        Mono<DemoPOJO>      monoDemoPOJO  = null;
        Map<String, String> pathVariables = request.pathVariables();
        int                 id            = -1;

        checkRepoRef(); // part of the list hack

        // short-circuit if request doesn't contain id (should never happen)
        if ((pathVariables == null)
         || (!pathVariables.containsKey(PATH_VAR_ID))) {
            return ServerResponse.badRequest().build();
        }

        // short-circuit if bad id value
        try {
            id = Integer.parseInt(pathVariables.get(PATH_VAR_ID));
        } catch(NumberFormatException e) {
            return ServerResponse.badRequest().build();
        }

        // get entity by keyValue
        monoDemoPOJO = repo.getById(id);

        return monoDemoPOJO
                   .flatMap(demoPOJO -> ServerResponse.ok()
                                                      .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
                                                      .syncBody(demoPOJO)
                   .switchIfEmpty(ServerResponse.notFound().build()));
    }

}
```

Hack of a list-based repo to avoid dealing with data/APIs while working on handlers and http return types.

```
// local hack to avoid a database for testing
public class DemoPOJORepo {

    private static DemoPOJORepo fpRepo   = null;
    private static int          NUM_ROWS = 100;

    private Map<Integer, DemoPOJO> fooPOJOMap;

    private DemoPOJORepo() {
        initMap();
    }

    public static DemoPOJORepo getInstance() {
        if (fpRepo == null) {
            fpRepo = new DemoPOJORepo();
        }
        return fpRepo;
    }

    public Mono<DemoPOJO> getById(int id) {
        Mono<DemoPOJO> monoDP;

        if (fooPOJOMap.containsKey(id)) {
            monoDP = Mono.just(fooPOJOMap.get(id));
        } else {
            monoDP = Mono.empty();
        }
        return monoDP;
    }

    private Mono<Void> initMap() {
        fooPOJOMap = new TreeMap<Integer, DemoPOJO>();
        int offset = -1;

        for(int ndx=0; ndx<NUM_ROWS; ndx++) {
            offset = ndx + 1;
            fooPOJOMap.put(offset, new DemoPOJO(offset, "foo_" + offset, offset+100));
        }
        return Mono.empty();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your brackets are in the wrong place causing the swithIfEmpy to apply to the `ServerResponse.ok()` publisher not the `monoDemoPOJO`, replace the return with this and it should work:

```
return monoDemoPOJO
                   .flatMap(demoPOJO -> ServerResponse.ok().contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON).syncBody(demoPOJO))
                   .switchIfEmpty(ServerResponse.notFound().build());
```

Comment: Thank you. As with many things, it's not the "new and cool" that often trips you up, it's the "familiar and mundane".

Answer (score 0):

As I can see the code is right. The response code is Bad request because you are trying to convert "foo" to Integer, and when it throws an exception you are returning a Bad request response, so I think it works perfectly fine. 
If you use an Integer id that is not present in your database then the answer must be a not found response

Comment: My issue/concern is not the "Bad Request" returned when "foo" is supplied as an int value. The issue/concern is that "the answer must be a not found response" is returning "okay" with an empty body (vice "not found" with an empty body).

Comment: Ok, I didn't understand the problem. I think the problem is that the switchIfEmpty operation is associated to the inner mono, the one you use to create the response in ok case, and this will never be empty. You have to close the brackets of the flatmap before the switchIfEmpty operation